# My Flutter app is crashing when i am using zegocloud prebuilt ui call kit

Tags: android, flutter, videocall, zegocloud

I am using zegocloud prebuilt ui kit and it is crashing when i am opening the apk after building apk using flutter build apk command. can anyone also faced the same problem and if anyone faced this same problem please let me know also the solution you used to fix this issue.
Thanks for help..

I am facing this issue while creating apk with command - flutter build apk.
Also i am new to flutter.

Comment: try to first run your app in release mode and check the potential error in the console "flutter run -v --release"

Comment: i tried this command and after executing this command after this i am getting this error attaching the gist of the stacktrace of android.

Link ----https://gist.github.com/Gagnar1999/59068db697c178fa0503a5a1e428a21c

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if you have created `proguard-rules.pro` file if not then In your project's your_project > android > app folder, create a proguard-rules.pro file with the following content as shown below:

```
-keep class **.zego.**  { *; }
-keep class **.**.zego_zpns.** { *; }
```

The reason for crash is that in android release mode `proguard` will obstructed code so you need to add this in proguard file.

you can check in there doc to here the link : https://docs.zegocloud.com/article/14826